# Merge Win32 c++ dll with managed c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a c++ project compiled with /clr support(e.g. wrapper.dll). This project(wrapper.dll) is a wrapper between .Net enviroment and unmaged dll(e.g. noCode.dll), which inherits from. I dont have access to code of inherited dll(noCode.dll), but I can link it to my wraper (by noCode.lib and noCode.h files).

When I want to use my wraper(wrapper.dll) in c# project I reference it **and have to copy my unmanaged dll(noCode.dll)** to location of c# project execution.

Is it possible to merge c++ unmamaged dll(noCode.dll) to managed dll(wrapper.dll) to allow to use **only one file** by reference(noCodeWrapper.dll) in c# projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to link DLL files together.

But you can add that nocode.LIB to your DLL and then you don't need [DllImport]. Since you have LIB and H files, you can call the "nocode" functions directly from your managed C++ code.

Comment: Yes, but still if I reference wrapper.dll in any c# project I have to copy nocode.dll to its working directory. I wonder if it's possible to avoid this?

Comment: You cannot merge your wrapper and "nocode" together, but you can merge the wrapper and client application together. That way you will have only client.exe and nocode.dll, but not wrapper.dll.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarification. P.S. why I've got -1? Is my question so obvious?

Answer (score 1):

If you had access to noCode.dll source code you could integrate it with wrapper.dll. Otherwise merging DLL binaries is not a task that could give predictable results.